# Does the AcI permit the use of adjectives?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, accusativus-cum-infinitivo

My question stems from a passage in Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata Familia Romana in chapter 12 on page 90 beginning at line 117 as follows.

> << "Mīles Rōmānus, quī hostem armātum accurrere uidet, nōn ab eō fugit, sed armīs sē dēfendit. >>

My understanding of active infinitive verbs informs that the subject of 'accurrere' is 'Mīles Rōmānus', however I am yet to have the distinction of whether Accūsātīvus cum Īnfīnītīuō permits adjectives.

**Question:** Does 'hostem armātum' form part of an AcI with 'accurrere'?

Comment: When I read this sentence I see the _hostis armatus_ as the subject of _accurrere_. I don’t claim any grand authority for this but it does seem to make the sentence make more sense.

Comment: "My understanding of active infinitive verbs informs that the subject of 'accurrere' is 'Mīles Rōmānus'" -- what, pray, do you think this sentence actually means?

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel I am of the opinion that the sentence informs that a Roman soldier does not flee but defends himself with arms. The object of the initial consternation if it had to be defined might concern the function of an object in relation to a verb phrase, however the question was answered well by cmw, and given extra light by Mitomino.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, *hostem armatum* is part of the AcI.

In AcI/Indirect Statements, the subject of the infinitive is in the accusative. In this case, *hostem* is the subject, not *miles*. *Miles* instead is the subject of *fugit* and the antecedent of *qui*, which in turn is the subject of *uidet*. Without all that, the basic sentence would be:

> Hostis accurrit.

Adjectives aren't treated specially. The *armatum* agrees with *hostem* regardless of what *hostem* is doing or in what construction it's in.

Comment: Perhaps a relevant point to be noted is that in the OP's question _armatum_ can be an attributive modifier ([NP _hostem armatum_]) or a predicative one ([NP _hostem_] [_armatum_]). Perhaps the OP's question is whether the subject of an AcI construction can be modified by a predicative adjective, which is of course possible. Perhaps the question is whether _quī hostem armātum accurrere uidet_ can be understood as a sort of an extension of _quī hostem armātum uidet_. It's really difficult to find a sense to the question above...

Comment: @Mitomino I would not have read that much into the question. I suppose we should wait until the OP clarifies.

Comment: I am here inclined to read 'armātum' as an attributive modifier for its simplicity despite its locality, however as a predicative adjective I think it affords a richer sense for 'uidet' within the whole sentence and I appreciate the food for thought.

Comment: @Mr.Blythe Did this answer your question, or was it something else you were looking for?

Comment: @cmw Yes and I found your rationale particularly helpful. The comment by Mitomino added a facet to adjectival phrases that I had not previously considered.